# Change color or border to highlight specific bar in `geom_bar`

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am creating a bar chart considering two years and a set of countries. To do this, I am using the geom_bar function from the ggplot package. I would like to highlight the colors for a specific country only. Is there a way to do that?

Here's an example of the chart, which is similar to what I'm working on:

```
Panel <- read.dta("http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta")
Panel$y = Panel$y / 1000000

Panel %>%
  filter(year %in% c(1990, 1991)) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = country, y = y, fill = as.factor(year))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           position = 'dodge2', colour = 'white') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#001d87', '#d9912e')) +
  labs(fill = 'Year', x = 'Country') +
  theme_classic()
```

The goal is to highlight the colors for country C, for instance, by making the colors for this country more solid compared to the others or by adding distinctive borders, something that can differentiate this country without affecting the legend. I appreciate any assistance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put `color` within `aes`, then supply a vector of named vector specifying the colors of each country.

```r
library(foreign)
library(tidyverse)

Panel <- read.dta("http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta")
Panel$y = Panel$y / 1000000

Panel %>%
  filter(year %in% c(1990, 1991)) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = country, y = y, fill = as.factor(year), color = country)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           position = 'dodge2') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#001d87', '#d9912e')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(c(rep("white", 2), "red", rep("white", 4)), LETTERS[1:7]), guide = NULL) +
  labs(fill = 'Year', x = 'Country') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>